# Angularjs ng-repeat and child elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to insert a `<br/>` every nth element to achieve something like this (using ng-repeat and ng-if="!($index % 2)"):

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <br/>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought I could mimic how i've used ng-repeat in the past for `<ul/>` elements, as so:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which produces a list such as this:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Yet when I attempt to do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get this differing result from the `<ul/>` usecase:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question is two-fold:

- Why does the ng-repeat directive on a `<ul/>` behave differently
- How can I have multiple span elements then a break without wrapping each span in a div?

Comment: Do you really need a br tag? Can't you achieve the same results with CSS using the nth-child selector?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.

In your loop, your 'item' has following local variables: **$index, $first, $middle, $last, $even, $odd**. Each except $index returns a boolean value that tells you if the item is, for example, $odd. Also take a look at the directive [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven).

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat acts equal to any tag, maybe the presatantion of ul creates confusion,

look next example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ig766DNNlQXihNS5ZGdY?p=preview

im separated:

```
 <ul class="example-animate-container">
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends">
```

and

```
<legeng>ul - ng repeat</legeng>
<ul class="example-animate-container" ng-repeat="friend in friends">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you want to insert a `<br>` every nth `<span>` then you can change your HTML to the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <span ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}

          <br ng-if="$index % 2">
     </span>
</div>
```

Tested in Firefox,Chrome,and Internet Explorer the results look like this:

```
12
34
56
```

All you have to do is remove the surrounding div elements and then change your html to the following(live preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/qbJXJm). The `ng-repeat` directive duplicates the number of child elements that are contained within the parent element. The `<li>` elements in your example do not contain any child elements. In other words `<li>` elements are child elements of the `<ul>` element by default.  However `<span>` elements are not child elements of `<div>` elements by default.  You will see similar behavior when you use `ng-repeat` for other elements like the `<table>` element and its `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="spans">

   <div id="container">
        <span ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}
          </span>
  </div> 

      </div>
```

Angular/JavaScript:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("spans", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

}]);
```

And if you want each span to have a line break then apply the following CSS:

```
#container span {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div ng-repeat="num in [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
  <div>{{num}}</div>
  <div ng-if="$index%2">whatever you want</div>
</div>
```

### Result looks something like this.

```
1
2
whatever you want
3
4
whatever you want
5
6
whatever you want
```